# Deploying Groovy and React Application to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, gradle, groovy, ratpack

I currently have a Ratpack Groovy application hosted on heroku, I've managed to get it working correctly and deploying to the URL Heroku created for me. I decided to make a ReactJS application, which grabs the data from my database from an API I've built in Ratpack, my React application acts as a basic CMS where I can post data back to Ratpack and update the database.

My front end templates get rendered from within my Ratpack handlers, this all works fine locally. I followed

https://github.com/gschrader/ratpack-react-boilerplate

Here is my basic project structure

[image]

So I can run ./gradlew run which builds the react app and starts up my Ratpack app in the root of my project and then yarn start in my React directory which starts up my react application on localhost:3000.

My question is how do I deploy this on Heroku, at the moment it's in one big directory, so could I deploy it as one project? I'd like the cms to be on a sub domain such as admin.application.com. I am pretty confused as to how this would work, if anyone has any documentation that would be very helpful.